# How do I refer to myself or to the text I am writing in a neutral way in an academic context?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

My PhD supervisor and also myself we prefer the neutral form to refer to oneself or the text that is written instead of saying "I will …" or "As I have shown …".

I know some expressions to do so but need more variations.

Comment: "The writer" maybe?

Comment: The two main methods are using "We" and using the passive voice. Another possible method is to refer to your team in the third person (along with other terms such as "the researchers", "the team", and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternatives to use:

"the writer", "this writer", "the author", "we", "your correspondent", etc

Measures to take to avoid using "I":

Using passive voices, removing unnecessary "I parts" like "I found", "I observed", etc.

Answer (score 0):

My professors always taught us to use the impersonal way to refer to ourself or to our group (we), on the other hand we would be penalize  . But some of them have said that the impersonal form isn't obligatory into academic essays. 
Personally i have never agreed with the impersonal form and in every cases the correctors haven't penalized me.

Answer (score 0):

In college, I was taught to use the passive voice when writing scientific papers. But in math, I was taught to use "we", as if the reader was preforming the math proofs along with the author as they read along.

I think either is potentially acceptable depending on the situation. When in doubt, look at a relevant journal's style guide.